# When a function is equal to a certain value

Tags: r, statistics

I am extremely new to R, so the solution to this is probably relatively simple. I have the following function to calculate stopping distance for an average car:

```
distance <- function(mph){(2.0*(mph/60))+(0.062673*(mph^1.9862))}
```

And I'm plotting all stopping distances from 1 mph to 60 mph:

```
range = distance(1:60)
```

But I need to mark where the stopping distance is equal to 120 ft. I don't have any idea how this is done in R, but I'd like to write a function where, for a stoppingdistance(x), I get the maximum speed of the car in MPH. What function should I use, and is there an easy way to check if the value of distance(x) (as it's written above) is equal to a certain value?

Comment: You might have a couple of questions there. You've mentioned plotting and finding where the stopping distance is equal to 120 feet, but is this only for the plot? Are you asking how to find this point? Are you asking how to draw a vertical line on the graph at this point? Both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be to find when the function -120 is equal to 0:

```
distance <- function(mph, dist=0){(2.0*(mph/60))+(0.062673*(mph^1.9862))-dist}
uniroot(distance, c(1, 60), dist=120)
## $root
## [1] 44.63998
##
## $f.root
## [1] -5.088982e-06
##
## $iter
## [1] 6
##
## $estim.prec
## [1] 6.103516e-05
```

And to see if it worked:

```
distance(44.63998)
## [1] 120
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and has an accepted answer, but I want to point out another way to accomplish this - create the inverse function. Since you have the function, it is easy to generate many x-y points over a plausible range. Then simply create the inverse function by making y be a function of x. In your example,

```
x = seq(0,150,0.05)
y = distance(x)
speed = approxfun(y,x)
```

Now let's confirm that it gives good answewrs:

```
speed(120)
[1] 44.63998
distance(speed(120))
[1] 120
```